# creating static frame and changing content pages in flex

Tags: apache-flex, layout

I need to create a static frame and a changing content... currently envisaged as frame containing the side panel and header and footer content.

The content panel will call mxml based on the content sought. Two questions
a) how is the frame paradigm- with static frame "containing" other content done. I dont want to repeat the header and footer logic in every 'content section' code?
b) how is the hyperlinking between content sections done- using 'states' seems convoluted

Any guidance around this will be appreciated

Raghu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok- managed to get this right

I added the 100% height and width to the moduleloader and it fills the container and resizes fine... not sure why but this has resolved the endless animation also

thanks folks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of flex you are using, but I'm advising to use latest Flex 4 codename Gumbo, with next features:

[read about states](http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/States/)

[and about containers](http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/SWFLoader/)

[and how to build modules too](http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/Module/)

Hope it will help you, but anyway you should share your ideas more clearly and put some startup code, so we could assist you to get your goals done.

Regards
Eugene

Comment: Thanks for the tip...
I tried with modules and it seems to make sense... i get the ability to structure each page content as a separate mxml so it becomes easier to handle. 

I am having a relatively smaller problem with the module. As i embed an image and animation seeig two problems
a) the image does not fit within its cotainer 100% width and height as it did when it was in parent mxml
b) animation timer resets after timer stop- to create a endless loop. Again something which executes fine in the parent mxml

Comment: <mx:Image height="100%" width="100%" source="background.jpg" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true"  depth="1"/>  
<s:Button label="Start" id="playButton"  depth="2" x="1" y="38" click="playButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
<mx:Image x="{MainContent.width/20}" y="{MainContent.height*3/5}" source="car.png" maintainAspectRatio="true" height="15" id="car" depth="3"/>

Comment: 1)use pastebin.com or just edit your question. 2) and yes, feel the difference http://pastebin.com/6RjXEse3

Comment: i had assumed that the container in the module will understand the size of container in the parent application that it resides in- doesn't work that way...no resizing occurs

pls guide on how i can make it explict

Comment: once again give me your current code, and tell me which component you want to resize on which event.

Comment: pls look at http://pastebin.com/XQnWsXYU
I have 3 problems that come once i move the animation to a separate module
a) not able to get the sizig to work- e.g. image doesnt fill the container at 100% height and width and aspect ratio=false. 
b) Likewise doesnt resize when browser size changes
c) animation acts funny- doesnt run till 90% of container width; also runs in endless loop